# Continuity of Conditional Law

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the set of all Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the weak topology.  Let $X_t$ be a strong solution to the SDE with initial conditions
$$
dX_t = \mu_tdt + \sigma_t dW_t, \mbox{    } X_0=x
$$
for some Lipschitz-continuous functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and a Brownian motion $W_t$.  Denote its conditional law $\nu_{t,x}:=\mathbb{P}(X_t \in \cdot|X_0=x)$.

Is the map $(x,t)\mapsto \nu_{t,x}$ from $\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty)$ to $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ever continuous?

**What I've tried:**
I tried to use the Feynman-Kac formula or approach the problem somehow using disintegration, but it doesn't seem to be clear how to go about it; or even if the "result" is true..

Comment: With the assumptions you have at the moment I don't think so. Even when working with ODE, don't we require some Lipschitz continuity to ensure continuous dependence on initial conditions?

Comment: @DanielAdams yes that's correct (unless we want to work with SD Inclusions...which I don't :P )  Thanks for pointing that out.